# asp.net core api first request slow after idletime on aws setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Angular + Asp.net Core 3.1 Web api which is integrated with OpenIDConnect using Cookie Authentication
for the Single Sign on(OneLogin).I am not not using Identity.
Angular is published on Asp.net core on IIS ( same domain) on aws setup(iis and sql server on separate box)
Cookie expiration is 7 hours as configured in Startup.cs.
App Pool is set to Always Running and Process Idle time = 0, Idle timeout action suspend
On the Application Preload enabled is true.

I am facing the issue where after every certain idle time (like 5 min that too randomly), when i refresh the home page,
api calls take long to complete for the first request,
I check the query execution time for these calls in profiler and they are fast.

When I run the same app with same app pool settings on a server having both IIS 10 and sql server, I face no so issue and loading is fast throughout the day.

What could be causing the api calls to be slow? What can be best way to fix this.

Comment: There are two reasons may cause api calls to be slow. First is network and second is application Idle time. So check the log of application server when angular send call request. Compare the time of server receive request and angular send request. If the time difference is large, it is most likely a network factor.

Comment: @Bruce Zhang- When I check the Windows logs on application server, the app pool /process does not restart after idle time refreshing(because we have it always running).  Where can I check the logs of client send request/ server receive request. When I check in developer options , api call request response timings, I see like Request sent duration 0.59 ms, Waiting (TTFB) 21.18s, Content Download 10.09ms.

Comment: If you don't know how to check the time angular call API. You can use some tool like postman to simulate angular sending a request to call the API, when you send it is when the API is called.